# Cloud service ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I am working with azure cloud service.

I tried to deploy simple web role to azure as cloud service. My web role just a simple asp net mvc app which convert html to pdf(I am using hiqpdf for conversion)  without connection to db.

My web role deployed successfully, Virtual Machine was created and i can access my site through rdp on local iis of VM.

But i cannot access site through public url(my.cloudapp.net) b/c of error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. Right now, there's not enough info. For example: Is there a database your app is using?

Comment: I just added updates. Let me know if you need more information

Comment: How did you install hiqpdf? Doesn't that require an installer with elevated privileges? Have you tried deploying without that component?

Comment: Without hiqpdf have the same issue